# Unable to add button in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, gui, gameobject

I am wanting to add a button to my scene in order to mute/unmute music.  I can add the button to my scene, but it's not appearing on the UI.  I can't see it anywhere, not on the scene nor the game when running.

Below is a screenshot of the editor.  You can see the button in front of the camera and in front of the scene itself, but it doesn't appear.  I can't actually see a button, just a 'move' control'.

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Changing the 'Layer' of the button to default
- Adjusting the z-axis (I've tried 0, +1-5, -1-5)
- Giving the `Image (Script)` a material inside the Inspector

The button has text, which isn't visible either.

I could create a sprite and do a raycast, but that seems like overkill just to do a simple click action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `Button` a child of a `Canvas`.